# Can I trigger a git hook after a commit from Gitlab web editor?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, git-post-receive, post-commit-hook

I use git, specially in conjunction with Gitlab (7.7.1 + shell 2.4.1), to wire together a bunch of parts of my development workflow. The post important part of this is the post-receive hooks that happen on the server end that run various tests and builds. The [introduction of custom hooks](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/667c0a909bde1cf71f21d8ec9768e98b1c489030/doc/hooks/custom_hooks.md) has made this a lot easier as I no longer have to monkey with the Gitlab code to recover the hook positions it was previously hijacking.

The `post-receive` hook in this location works great for all commits coming in via SSH. The problem I have is that these hooks do not seem to be called when the web interface built in editor is used to make a commit. I've tried putting a `post-commit` hook in the custom_hooks folder of my repo but it does not seem to get called. It seems like this lack of hook calling is also the case if I use the HTTPS address for connecting to git rather than SSH.

Is there a way to configure Gitlab or a place to put my hooks such that it will be called for all commits that hit the repository, not just remote pushes via SSH?

Answer (score 2):

Custom hooks ([introduced with gitlab-shell 2.2.0 and Gitlab 7.5+](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/8276/files)) don't seem to be triggered through web ui edit file action ([`gitlab/satellite/files/edit_file_action.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/gitlab/satellite/files/edit_file_action.rb)).

This is reported in [issue 8428](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8428), and is still pending.